# rails 3.2, bootstrap and fontface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, font-face, twitter-bootstrap

I was building an app on rails 3.2 with bootstrap-sass.  Everything was fine until I installed fontface.  I think fontface overrode bootstrap because the app looks completely messed up now.  Has anyone else had this issue or suggest how i can fix this?

I already deleted the fontface files from the app and deleted all (I think) references to it, but couldn't figure it out.

Of course, noob mistake, I didn't fork it to github in the past few days and a lot of work has been done since.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: "Messed up" can mean alot of things - care to elaborate what exactly breaks?

Comment: a lot of the formatting is lost.  for example, the navigation bar is stacked on top of one another instead of next to each other; the row and span classes are lost, etc.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled bootstrap-sass but that didn't do the trick unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the reason it "messed up" was because I had updated to bootstrap-sass 2.0 from 1.4.4 and I guess it wasn't compatible with what I had already done, I suppose.  The weird thing is although I had upgraded a few days ago, it had just showed up that it was incompatible.  Maybe I just hadn't restarted my server since then.

If anyone had the same issue before and knows how to fix it, please let me know as I would like to upgrade to 2.0.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of the classes etc changed from Bootstrap 1.4 to 2.0. Check Twitter's changelog if you're still updating.